# Convert datetime YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ into Indian standard time local like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm AM/PM

Tags: process-builder, datetime, timezone

I have one field start(API Name-starttime) at event standard object. i cannot create custom field on Event object due to salesforce constraints. I am using this [Event].starttime value in process builder for some variable . I am getting value as YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ but i want to display as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm AM/PM as indian standard time. I am basically sending SMS using third party app and in SMS i need to mention event starttime. I am unable to get in IST format. is there any way to convert like this.

Comment: Is there a way to manipulate dates in a process builder?  If not maybe you can create a formula and manipulate it that way, then you would read from the forumla not the `startime`, you may have to get creative .. found this though https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181642&language=en_US

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to define an Invocable Method in Apex that converts the DateTime to the users preferred format. Then call that method from Process Builder.

See [InvocableMethod Annotation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) and the [DateTime format() methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_format).